# "See you all" or "see you everyone"

Tags: nouns, pronouns, speech, you-all

When leaving from work, how to say "see you" to colleagues? Which one is appropriate, "see you all" or "see you everyone"?

Comment: Both sound awkward to me. I'd just say "See you".

Comment: Suppose you were welcoming the people you're addressing, rather than saying you'll see them [later]? Would you say *"Welcome you all"*, or *"Welcome everyone"*? I think in general when people (esp. Americans) say *you all* (or *y'all*) it's just the pluralised form of *you* as might be addressed to a single other person.

Comment: To me, "okay, well, see you all later/tomorrow" sounds perfectly fine (just replace the vowel sound in you with schwa). "See you everyone" sounds awkward.

Comment: @FumbleFingers your two options are inconsistent, you removed the 'you' to make "Welcome everyone," but didn't remove it in the other case to make "Welcome all" which sounds fine.

Comment: @Luke: Except in some parts of the (southern) U.S., one might hear "See you all later," albeit in its contracted form (i.e., "See y'all later...")

Comment: @J.R. Don't forget' y'all is singular.... all y'all is plural. XD

Comment: "See you all" is used in the states. It's colloquial.  And it's not the same as its drawled (southern) cousin: See y'all. The pronunciation is different but the meaning is the same:  You all and y'll are the same thing. And there's the even shorter: See ya.

Answer (score 2):

From the ones you proposed, only *see you all* is correct, because "you all" equals "everyone."

Another example would be:

> I have won everything.

Which equals to:

> I have won it all.

On the same idea, "I have met everyone" equals "I have met them all."

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  If you add *later* (without which, I’m not crazy about either option), then both options are possible, but in different ways:

> See you all later! 
>  See you later, everyone!

Here, *everyone* is a vocative.  Compare:

> See you later, guys/Jim! 
>   Welcome, guys/Jim/everyone! (the last being FumbleFingers’ example above)

*All* has a more restricted use as a vocative, for reasons I don’t understand.  For instance, *Welcome, all!* is (for me) ok, but there is a marked contrast between:

> Pick up your pens, everyone, and begin 
>  ?? Pick up your pens, all, and begin

Swapping things around:

> See you later, all!

is sayable (my father might use it), but it is completely impossible to say:

> See you everyone later!

This is part of a systematic contrast:

> Scots all are nice 
>  Scots are all nice 
>   *Scots everyone are nice 
>  *Scots are everyone nice
>
> You all are nice 
>  You are all nice 
>   *You everyone are nice 
>  *You are everyone nice
>
> All the girls are nice 
>  The girls are all nice 
>   *Everyone the girls are nice 
>  *The girls are everyone nice

In short, *everyone* consists of a (quantificational) determiner (*every*) and a nominal element (*one*) and so leaves no space other determines (*the*, *you*) or other nominal elements (*Scots*, *girls*).  So, you can’t interpret *you everyone* as a single determiner phrase.  Yet neither can *everyone* “float” away from a nominal, as *all* does in *You are all nice*.  So, there’s just no grammatical parse of *See you everyone later* at all.